# Correct GTK CSS selector to use from SWT widgets?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, gtk, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to apply GTK+ 3 CSS rules to widgets used in the Eclipse UI, specifically for a ComboBox right now. For example: say I want to make the background color of a selected text in a combobox to be red. The Style rule applied to the combobox widget would be

```
*.entry:selected { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

I have proven that rule using the Gtk+ CSS Inspector tool in Ubuntu and that works there but I do not find a way to apply that rule in code for ComboBoxes.

Inside SWT, there are places where CSS is used on Linux, such as this snippet to set the background color, however, adding the above rule to the CSS override does not have any apparent impact (yes, the background color does work).

```
@Override
void setBackgroundColor (long /*int*/ context, long /*int*/ handle, GdkRGBA rgba) {
    // CSS to be parsed for various widgets within Combo
    background = rgba;
    String css = "* {\n";
    if (rgba != null) {
        String color = display.gtk_rgba_to_css_string (rgba);
        css += "background: " + color + ";\n";
    }
    css += "}\n";
    // Cache background color
    cssBackground = css;
    String finalCss = display.gtk_css_create_css_color_string (cssBackground, cssForeground, SWT.BACKGROUND);

    //Injected code to make selected text red
    finalCss += "\n.*:selected {background-color: #FF0000}";
    if (entryHandle == 0 || (style & SWT.READ_ONLY) != 0) {
        // For read only Combos, we can just apply the background CSS to the GtkToggleButton.
        gtk_css_provider_load_from_css (OS.gtk_widget_get_style_context(buttonHandle), finalCss);
    } else {
        if (OS.GTK_VERSION >= OS.VERSION(3, 16, 0)) {
            // For GTK3.16+, only the GtkEntry needs to be themed.
            gtk_css_provider_load_from_css (OS.gtk_widget_get_style_context(entryHandle), finalCss);
        } else {
            // Maintain GTK3.14- functionality
            setBackgroundColorGradient (OS.gtk_widget_get_style_context (entryHandle), handle, rgba);
            super.setBackgroundColor (OS.gtk_widget_get_style_context (entryHandle), entryHandle, rgba);
        }
    }
    // Set the background color of the text of the drop down menu.
    OS.g_object_set (textRenderer, OS.background_rgba, rgba, 0);
}
```

I’ve tried various combinations of selectors and so far have not found a way to have the “selection” background color of the text to take effect.

Here is a link to the corresponding ComboBox class from SWT where it deals with CSS -- see the setBackgroundColor method.

https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/gtk/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Combo.java

I have proven that code runs and also managed to change the background for the entire combobox by changing the css rule there. However, if I inject my new rule it gets ignored.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If this is an Eclipse 4.x RCP it has its own CSS code which is probably overriding the base SWT code [Eclipse 4 CSS Styling](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html)

Comment: Hello @greg-449. While this is E4 based, the E4 CSS appears to use SWT APIs which ultimately map into this code. I can see E4 CSS background color changes going through this method.